# evaluate the Matern kernel with custom distances

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm trying to evaluate the matern kernel from the scikit learn package. So basically, I do something like this

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern as skMatern

locs=np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.7]])

K = skMatern(nu=1.8, length_scale=0.2)
covMat = K(locs)
```

My problem is that I want to be able to determine the way the kernel calculates distances between the points.

In other words, the code I have above calculates

[image]

where [image] is the Matern covariance function and [image], [image] are rows of the `locs` array. What I would like is to calculate [image] and be able to specify d myself (maybe as a distance matrix). I've been looking at the `scikit-learn` documentation but haven't been able to figure out how to do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but it could help someone else. If `d` is your distance matrix, you can write :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

m, n = 10, 3
d = pairwise_distances(np.random.randn(m, n))

K = Matern()(0, d.ravel()[:, np.newaxis]).reshape(d.shape)
```

This line of code benefits from the fact that `0` is broadcasted to the right shape.